# where can I find all kendo ui versions

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I am trying to find all versions or it's dates for KendoUI controls History. However I found history dates from April 2014 onwards.

http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history

does any body have list of all version dates.

Thanks In Advance,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Before 2014, its distributed name was Kendo UI Web. You can find related version list with release dates on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoUIWeb/